# webpack-dev-server and nginx locally, how to run it with localhost, not localhost:8081?

Tags: nginx, webpack-dev-server

So, I posted previously, but I will narrow the question a bit to. How can I develop locally and using webpack-dev-server (local development only) and instead of defaulting to something like:

localhost:8081

make it so its localhost

I believe this can be achieved via nginx running locally. Is this possible? or do I need an express proxy?

Any ideas/tutorials?

So, right now when I go to my site I have to do this:

```
localhost:8081/aboutUs
localhost:8081/signin
```

I want, instead to do:

```
localhost/aboutUs
localhost/signin
```

Comment: It is not very well understood what you want, is to access by localhost:80 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port number webpack-dev-server listens on in the file webpack.config.js, this way it will stop listening on port 8080 and use the port of your choice.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverport

If you do not want the port in the URL, you have to use the default port for the protocol, in this case it is http so "80".

Comment: I don't want to change it per se, I just want it so that when I go to my site locally its not: localhost:8081, but rather "localhost". The port is NOT in the url. Of course, I KNOW it will have a port, but I am proxy'ing it so it resolves to localhost.

Comment: For port to not be in the url you have to use the default port for the protocol, so for eg for http you need to use port 80. You'll need to be running the server as a user with root to use any port below 1024